# Argparse, toggle what arguments corresponds to stdin

Tags: python-3.x, argparse

I'm looking in to a way to take two arguments, with `argparse` such that 
given a flag, it will toggle what `dest` variable will get it's value from `stdin`.

The use case is providing a cli tool I'm writing with two ways of providing data.

as an example this 4 commands should be equivalent when It comes to the final `namespace` before calling the functions to process it.

```
cat data.json | template-engine --template template.htm --json-stdin
template-engine --template template.htm --json-data data.json
template-engine --template <(cat template.htm) --json-data <(cat data.json)
cat template.htm | template-engine --json-data data.json
```

This question, doesn't involve much code because from what I've read in the documentation this looks difficult, but I think that with an `action` class this could be done, but I'm not entirely sure how.

Any Ideas?

Just to be clear, I want to do this with `argparse` not any other command line interface library.

I tried using an action, that will check what is the source of the variable value, but If I assign a default value for one of the arguments, it causes issues.

Some of the questions here I want to do are:

- Has anyone already done this? (So I can go and look how to manage the streams)
- Could I do this just using `argparse` tools, or should I implement logic post parsing.

Comment: It's not obvious what you are trying to do.  But: Make sure the `sys.argv` that you get in each case makes sense.  That's all the `argparse` works with.  Start a basic parsing without fancy action.  Don't be afraid of post parsing code; `argparse` is primarily a parser (what does the user want), not a whole script engine.  Show actual `argparse` code.

Comment: This seems like an interesting question, but I don't fully understand what you're trying to achieve. Could you describe the desired behavior of your application in more detail, instead of mainly posting some example commands? And maybe you could also explain the 3th example command, since I'm not familiar with that specific syntax. And could you describe what you've tried already (post some code) and be more specific than "it causes issues"?

Comment: `argparse` doesn't do anything directly with `stdin`.  It parses the command line arguments, the strings in `sys.argv[1:]`.  One or more of those strings may be a file name (or even a string '-').  But as far as I can tell piping and file redirection does nothing to the command line values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's much simpler to use a hyphen `-` to indicate stdin, like most Unix tools do. For example:

```sh
template-engine --template template.htm --json data.json
cat data.json | template-engine --template template.htm --json -
cat template.htm | template-engine --template - --json data.json
```

To handle the hyphen, you could use `fileinput.input(files=[filename])` instead of doing it manually.